# creating life in the laboratory

Tags: evolution

Originally life came about through non life but Scientists are unable to achieve this in a laboratory . Why is this ? Is it the time factor ? I believe that it took one billion years for life to evolve here on Earth did it not ?

Comment: Should this not be tagged *abiogenesis* rather than *evolution*?

Comment: What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that science has moved on somewhat, and scientists have created 'living' (self-replicating) artificial bacterial cells. They built the genome
from physical materials and transplanted the engineered genome into an existing bacterial cell.  This site has a timeline of the history of the project https://www.jcvi.org/first-minimal-synthetic-bacterial-cell

Comment: So they have only built the genome and not an entire living cell ? How far away are they from creating a self replicating living organism ?

Comment: Well, they have built an entirely new self-replicating organism, but needed an empty cell to get it started.  They may not prioritise making a cell from scratch, because bacterial cells are plentiful.